# How to check if the frontmost application is in fullscreen?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, fullscreen

I need to know if the frontmost application is in fullscreen.
Here's what I have to check that (I know `NSApplicationPresentationOptions` only works with `NSApplication` but I don't know how to do it with the `NSRunningApplication`):

```
NSArray *activeApps = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isActive==YES && bundleIdentifier!=%@", MY_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER]];
if ([activeApps count] > 0){
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions opts = [[activeApps objectAtIndex:0] presentationOptions];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(setupPlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (opts & NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen) {
        //Do something
    }    
}
```

So, when I run the code, I obviously get the following error because `[activeApps objectAtIndex:0]` is a `NSRunningApplication` :

> -[NSRunningApplication presentationOptions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Any ideas on how to fix it and check if the frontmost application is in fullscreen? Or is there any other alternative to perform this?

Comment: The `runningApplications` array is of `NSRunningApplication`. `presentationOptions` applies to `NSApplication`, not `NSRunningApplication`, so that is why you get the error.  I'm not sure if there is a way to accomplish your goal, though.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I don't know any other way to convert a `NSRunningApplication` into  `NSApplication` to check the `presentationOptions` :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript for checking if the frontmost application is fullscreen or not.

The Script can be like,

1) Get the frontmost window of the application which is front.
2) Get the attribute value "AXFullScreen" of that window.

This will let you know if the front most app is fullscreen or not.'

Hope it Helps !!!